# Csv file with multiple lines in the same cell

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write down a CSV using python with multiple lines inside the same cell. For example i want the next result:

[image]

But I am getting this result:

[image]

I have tried several ways to insert a "\n" between both elements of the cell but not working. My last attempt was the next piece of code:

```
f=open("prueba.csv","a",newline="")
header=["Prueba","Prueba2"]
writer=csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(header)
prueba11="123"
prueba21="123"
prueba22="124"
prueba1=prueba11
prueba2=prueba21+"\n"+(prueba22)
prueba_write2=str(prueba2)
prueba_write1=str(prueba1)
row=[prueba_write1,prueba_write2]
writer.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Does somebody know if it is a easy way to get the desired result?
Thanks!

Comment: Please check your example code again and correct it. There are multiple errors in it. `prueba_write` isn't defined, aswell as `prueba`. `writer` isn't defined yet when writing the header.

Comment: Corrected! Even so, I don't think that those errors are determinant...any idea of how to achieve what I asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I can't imagine a usecase why you want to achieve that, but since you asked for it, here is one way to do it:
I changed a few things in the code to make it look more clean:

- Use context manager insted of open/close the file be hand
- (for me) I needed to add delimiter to `;` so I could open the result csv in Excel and got the desired result
- define the constant strings outside the context manager
- build your cell values with f-strings

```
header=["Prueba","Prueba2"]
p1 = "123"
p2 = "124"

with open("prueba.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(header)

    col1 = f"\n\n{p1}"
    col2 = f"{p1}\n{p2}\n"

    row = [col1, col2]
    print(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
prueba2=str(f'{prueba21}\n{prueba22}')
```

should result:

[image: result]

If you are concatenating variables with strings, try to use `f"Hello {variable}"` (fstrings) - recommended or `"Hello, %s." % variable`.

If you search python fstrings or string formating for python on google, you`ll have a better idea than i wrote here..

Also, if you have time, check this article/chapter from the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Sweigart -> [MANIPULATING STRINGS](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter6/) it helped me at the beginning of my python journey.

I had to drag the row wider in excel to see the "124" part.

Hope it helps.